# django-rest-framework how to make model serializer fields required

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that I'm filling out step by step, it means I'm making a form wizard.

Because of that most fields in this model are required but have `null=True, blank=True` to avoid raising not null errors when submitting part of the data.

I'm working with Angular.js and django-rest-framework and what I need is to tell the api that x and y fields should be required and it needs to return a validation error if they're empty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to override the field specifically and add your own validator. You can read here for more detail http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly. This is the example code.

```
def required(value):
    if value is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('This field is required')

class GameRecord(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    score = IntegerField(validators=[required])

    class Meta:
        model = Game
```

Answer (score 116):

The best option according to docs [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) is to use extra_kwargs in class Meta, For example you have UserProfile model that stores phone number and is required

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('phone_number',)
        extra_kwargs = {'phone_number': {'required': True}}
```

For this to work ensure that your models have been set as blank false null false as below.

```
some_field = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, default='Anonymous')
```

Comment: doesn't works, even with required true, objects with null values can be created

Comment: @VaibhavVishal, the above solution is not to avoid creating objects with NULL values, in the model if you have null=True, blank=True, objects will be created with null values. The solution above is to return a validation error to handle it as user level. I believe there is no way to avoid ORM not to create empty object values.

Comment: yeah my bad, in my case, i had to write a custom validator which check for values to be not `None` or `''`. Then used both, my custom validator and extra kwargs, required, to make sure user sends the value through api and doesn't sends an empty value.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal just add 'allow_null': False to the extra_kwargs

Answer (score 9):

This is my way for multiple fields. It based on rewriting UniqueTogetherValidator.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.utils.representation import smart_repr
from rest_framework.compat import unicode_to_repr

class RequiredValidator(object):
    missing_message = _('This field is required')

    def __init__(self, fields):
        self.fields = fields

    def enforce_required_fields(self, attrs):

        missing = dict([
            (field_name, self.missing_message)
            for field_name in self.fields
            if field_name not in attrs
        ])
        if missing:
            raise ValidationError(missing)

    def __call__(self, attrs):
        self.enforce_required_fields(attrs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode_to_repr('<%s(fields=%s)>' % (
            self.__class__.__name__,
            smart_repr(self.fields)
        ))
```

Usage:

```
class MyUserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( 'email', 'first_name', 'password' )
        validators = [
            RequiredValidator(
                fields=('email', 'first_name', 'password')
            )
        ]
```

Comment: Note that the report statemenents required for the __repr__ functions don't work any more in the latest version of django-rest-framework: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6879 .

Answer (score 7):

This works very well on my backend app.

```
class SignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        """ Serializer User Signup """
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username', 'password', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
            
            extra_kwargs = {'first_name': {'required': True, 'allow_blank': False}}
            extra_kwargs = {'last_name': {'required': True,'allow_blank': False}}
            extra_kwargs = {'email': {'required': True,'allow_blank': False}}
```

Comment: Good answer. You'll want to make the `extra_kwargs` like so:
`extra_kwargs = {
    'first_name': {'required': True, 'allow_blank': False},
    'last_name': {'required': True,'allow_blank': False},
    'email': {'required': True,'allow_blank': False}
}`

Answer (score 3):

According to [link1](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#emailfield) and [link2](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments), and due to the intended field is `null=True, blank=True` (like `email` field of `django.contrib.auth.models.User` in my example) this will work:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'email': {'required': True,
                                  'allow_blank': False}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `required` and `trim_whitespace` if you're using a CharField:

```
class CustomObjectSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, trim_whitespace=True)
```

`required` doc: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required
`trim_whitespace` doc: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield