# Django Rest Framework: how to make field required / read-only only for update actions such as PUT and PATCH?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I have a Django Serializer that has a field that should only be required for update actions such as PUT and PATCH. But not for create actions such as POST.

I found this similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30953481/80353) but there's no clue there regarding how to write a custom validation to detect whether an action is for create or update or patch.

Similarly, I want to turn on read_only (or make them not editable) for some other fields but only for update actions.

I have googled the django rest framework docs, but there's no explicit examples of such custom validators.

Right now, my workaround is to set `required=false` altogether which is not the best.

Please advise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can override the `get_fields` methods of `serializer` and then you can change the value of that fields

```
class SomeDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    some_field = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = super(SomeDataSerializer, self).get_fields(*args, **kwargs)
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request and getattr(request, 'method', None) == "POST":
            fields['some_field'].required = False
        return fields
```

Comment: Your code is not quite right. I edited it for what works for me.

Comment: it's always good to have request in context, by default all generic view of drf have this, if you do serialization intilization then it should be pass

Comment: For some reason, I had to use this way of extracting request. Then it works. No idea why.

Comment: you have  to pass request at time of serializer  object create, in view

Answer (score 20):

What I do in such situations is have a different serializer altogether that inherits from a base serializer and overrides the relevant fields. So in you case, an approach like this should work:

```
class CreateSerializer(serializers.Serializers):
    field = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

class UpdateSerializer(CreateSerializer):
    field = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
```

And in your view, return the relevant serializer:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.action == "POST":
        return CreateSerializer
    elif self.request.action in ["PUT", "PATCH"]:
        return UpdateSerializer
```

I think this is a good approach to take because you might need to add additional logic in the future based on the request method. It's also more readable than monkey patching the field's `required` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. but this results in a lot of repeated code for me. Anyway, I have solved it. Thankyou

Comment: This is actually an excellent answer. There wouldn't be "repeated code" since anything shared would go in the base, as stated.

Comment: Agreed, Saad's answer is a better option.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. Should be `self.request.method` rather than `self.request.action` on the current Django (3.0.x) version.

Comment: This is a cleaner way of achieving this! +1