# Django REST: Set all Serializer fields as not required at once

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Is there any way to set my serializer fields as not required by default? it'll take me hours to set every field of every serializer I have as not required so I wanted to know if there's any shortcut.

One example:

```
class ComputersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    serial = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    otherserial = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    contact = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    contact_num = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    comment = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    date_mod = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
    is_template = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    template_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    is_deleted = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_dynamic = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    ticket_tco = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4, required=False)
    uuid = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    date_creation = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
    is_recursive = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_inventory_update = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
    computertypes = ComputertypesSerializer(required=False)
    computermodels = ComputermodelsSerializer(required=False)
    entities = EntitiesSerializer(required=False)
    networks = NetworksSerializer(required=False)
    locations = LocationsSerializer(required=False)
    autoupdatesystems = AutoupdatesystemsSerializer(required=False)
    users = assistanceSerializers.UsersSerializer(required=False)
    groups = assistanceSerializers.GroupsSerializer(required=False)
    states = StatesSerializer(required=False)
    users_tech = assistanceSerializers.UsersSerializer(required=False)
    groups_tech = assistanceSerializers.GroupsSerializer(required=False)
    manufacturers = ManufacturersSerializer(required=False)
    

    class Meta: 
        model = Computers 
        fields = '__all__'
```

For the moment I had to set it for each field. I've been searching if someone had the same problem but it looks like I'm lazier than the rest of programmers.

Comment: I found an answer to another question related to this issue, that might help you: [Question: 'Django Rest Framework: how to make field required / read-only only for update actions such as PUT and PATCH?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736259/17597213)

Comment: There is [extra_kwargs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) in there to provide required False but not sure how you can override for all automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 class ComputersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
        class Meta: 
            model = Computers 
            fields = '__all__' 
            extra_kwargs = {field.name:{'required': False} for field in Computers._meta.get_fields()}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33435464)

Comment: Ok, but I neither criticized nor asked for clarification, I proposed a part of code which can be a solution to his problem. so i think i put my post in the right place. please to verify your review again. thank you ✌️

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the field optional, it should be defined in your model.
The ModelSerializer will react to that.

From [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required):

> If you're using Model Serializer default value will be False if you have specified blank=True or default or null=True at your field in your Model.