# Serializer is not valid

Tags: python, django, postgresql, serialization

When I try to make a POST request to my API endpoint to create a user in my Users table, I get mysterious Serializer errors. The error says that the `email`, `password`, `codename` (3 strings needed to create a user) are required. But I am sending all three strings. It is because the serializer is NOT valid (go to `serializers.py`, the `if serializer.is_valid()` check)... but I can't figure out why it's not valid.

Entire said error message:

```
{'codename': [ErrorDetail(string=u'This field is required.', code=u'required')], 'password': [ErrorDetail(string=u'This field is required.', code=u'required')], 'email': [ErrorDetail(string=u'This field is required.', code=u'required')]}
```

All these files are in my `users` folder within my Django directory.

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User

class UserPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'codename')
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import *
from .models import User
from argon2 import PasswordHasher
import json

@api_view(['POST'])
def create_user(request):
    print("inside create_user")
    """ POST = Create user. """
    data = {}
    # print("request.data:\n", request.data)
    serializer = UserPostSerializer(data=request.data)
    print("got serializer")
    if serializer.is_valid():
        print("serializer is valid!")
        email = serializer.data['email']
        codename = serializer.data['codename']
        password = serializer.data['password']

        user = User.objects.filter(email=email)

        if not user:
            # Apply Argon2
            ph = PasswordHasher()
            hash = ph.hash(password)

            # Create user
            new_user = User(email=email, password=hash, codename=codename)
            new_user.save()

            request.session['email'] = email
            request.session['id'] = new_user.pk
            print(request.session['email'], "has logged in!")
            print(request.session['id'], "user's id")
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        # User with this email found... Please login...
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)

    else:
        print(serializer.errors)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

models.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    profilePic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
```

Comment: how do you send the POST request?

Comment: I use Postman, I send a JSON dict. For ex: `{'email':'fake@gmail.com', 'password':'password', 'codename':'sneakyboi'}`

Comment: what does `print("request.data:\n", request.data)` print?

Comment: It prints: `('request.data:\n', <QueryDict: {u"{\n'email':'pizza@gmail.com',\n'password':'password',\n'codename':'sneakyass'\n}": [u'']}>)` (I changed the POST request, so it's different from above)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953481/django-rest-framework-how-to-make-model-serializer-fields-required) where they suggested to add `extra_kwargs` which specify that they are *not* required. This made my `if serializers.is_valid()` pass!

```
class UserPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'codename')
        extra_kwargs = {'email': {'required': False}, 'password': {'required': False}, 'codename': {'required': False}}
```