# Can unique_together avoid nulls in Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-2.0

I am using django and Sql server as a database.
I have a table with a multiple primary key using the `unique_together`

```
class Attribute_tmp(models.Model):
    useridtmp = models.ForeignKey(User_tmp, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank =True, null = True)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank =True, null = True)
    fk_str = models.ForeignKey(Stream, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
            unique_together = (('userid', 'fk_str'),('useridtmp', 'fk_str'))
```

So when i add objects of this table when the `useridtmp` is null, it doesn't work because i will have a duplicated key.

My Question is how can i avoid the null values.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
 class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['userid', 'fk_str'], name='name of constraint'),
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['useridtmp', 'fk_str'], name='another name of constraint')
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have null=True and blank=True in your ForeignKey field, it is reasonable for db to store null values.

If in any case, the two ForeignKeys shouldn't be null, you can mark null and blank as false. Simply removing them from field settings will do the trick as they are set to false by default. You probably need to [recreate the database](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html) to make the new settings working.

Then, the unique_together will not have an issue with null values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i can't do this change because sometimes i have the null values

Comment: In that case, you may need other methods to prevent "blank values"(form side) rather than "null value"(database side) inputted by users. This could either be done in your validation in your forms or you could use [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers) and [make the field required in meta class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835680/11607969).